# java: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds equality constraints: lower bounds: java.util.List<>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

i try to get a list from a stream but i have an exception.

Here is the Movie object with a list of an object.

```
public class Movie {

    private String example;
    private List<MovieTrans> movieTranses;

    public Movie(String example, List<MovieTrans> movieTranses){
        this.example = example;
        this.movieTranses = movieTranses;
    }
    getter and setter
```

Here is the MovieTrans:

```
public class MovieTrans {

    public String text;

    public MovieTrans(String text){
        this.text = text;
    }
    getter and setter
```

i add the element in the lists:

```
List<MovieTrans> movieTransList = Arrays.asList(new MovieTrans("Appel me"), new MovieTrans("je t'appel"));
List<Movie> movies = Arrays.asList(new Movie("movie played", movieTransList));
//return a list of MovieTrans
List<MovieTrans> movieTransList1 = movies.stream().map(Movie::getMovieTranses).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

i have this compiler error:

```
Error:(44, 95) java: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: MovieTrans
    lower bounds: java.util.List<MovieTrans>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `map` call in

```
movies.stream().map(Movie::getMovieTranses)
```

converts a `Stream<Movie>` to a `Stream<List<MovieTrans>>`, which you can collect into a `List<List<MovieTrans>>`, not a `List<MovieTrans>`.

To get a single `List<MovieTrans>`, use `flatMap` :

```
List<MovieTrans> movieTransList1 = 
    movies.stream()
          .flatMap(m -> m.getMovieTranses().stream())
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 10):

The type of your expression is `List<List<MovieTrans>>`: it's the concatenation of the results of the `getMovieTranses` method.

Use `flatMap` instead:

```
List<MovieTrans> movieTransList1 = movies.stream()
    .flatMap(m -> m.getMovieTranses().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: it isn't possible to call the method reference as parameter in flatMap. i do it with m -> m.getMovieTranses().stream()