# Java: Recursive pattern search for files (with relative paths) to pass as variable

Tags: java, regex, file, recursion, search

...thought this would be simple...  :/

I need to recursively search from the working directory (I can find this) for files matching a pattern, then pass each file as an input to a bufferedreader.

So far, I haven't been able to figure out type-matching between Paths, Files and Strings well enough to pass values between functions...

**Lil background:** This program will be moved to different folders, based on year and state, to parse text files into tabular format for data QA. I have the text file parsing code working great, but need to automate getting the log files for each county in a state.

I implemented code to find the current working directory:

```
File workingDir = new File(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
Path workDir = Paths.get(workingDir.getCanonicalPath());
```

I'm getting both, because I haven't made enough progress to know which I actually need...

I've (thank you SO!!) been able to recursively find all files from the working directory:

```
        Files.find(Paths.get(workDir.toString()),
        Integer.MAX_VALUE,
        (filePath, fileAttr) -> fileAttr.isRegularFile())
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to pass in a filter for the files that I want; or how to get the files into an iterable list to pass as an input file list for the bufferedreader.

```
    //List of input files for bufferedreader:
    java.util.List<String> inputFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
```

...and then changing the "Files.find(paths..." block to:

```
.forEach(inputFiles.add());
```

...doesn't work. I have no idea what to pass for arguments, and '...inputFiles.add()' won't compile (JDK 10) without arguments.

I tried a PathMatcher, but couldn't figure out how to type-match the function I was passing it to so the code would compile.

Here's my pattern, in standard regex:

```
Pattern logFile = Pattern.compile("Correct_[\\d]{4}-[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{2}_[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{2}.txt");
```

The pattern translates to: "Correct_yyyy-MM-dd_HH-MM.txt".

I couldn't get the following to compile, with a ".java:87: error: cannot find symbol" on 'Collector' in ".collect(Collectors.toList());":

```
inputFiles = Files.walk(Paths.get(workDir.toString()))
                            .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                            .map(Path::toFile)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I've imported java.io.*, java.io.File.*, java.nio.* & java.nio.file.* in the first lines of code.

Obviously, I don't understand file.io/file.nio, and I've been unable to generate working code after reading the Oracle docs/tutorials and numerous SO and other forums/sites.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you import java.util.strams.Collectors? without it, you cannot call on Collectors.toList()

Comment: @Assafs, eventually, but I ran into another won't compile error, then went to lunch.  --Got a meeting, but will fill in more details, shortly!
Thanks!!

Comment: It seems like this may require you going through debug steps. Once you go through all the obvious ones, if you still have an issue - please update the question with the new state and I will try to help.

Comment: @Assafs, With util.stream imported, I get ".java:88: error: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());"

I'm not far enough to debug, yet: I don't have even marginally working code.  :(

Comment: The problem is that we can't have this long conversation here. I'll write an answer below with what I know so far, and I'll edit it as you proceed. Is that OK?

Comment: @Assfs, sounds great! Thank you!

Comment: Done. If you think this helps you along, I'll appreciate it if you could vote-up the answer by clicking on the gray up-arrow next to it, and if you think this answers the question well enough, consider accepting it by clicking on the gray check mark next to it, making it green. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having found no walk-through, but numerous examples lacking explanations for WHY & HOW to run a recursive file search using regex and passing the result to a variable, I write one:

BE FOREWARNED: I'm a NOVICE. There's a lot I don't know or fully understand. I'm putting the state-of-the-art of **what I know** in this post - Please understand that "what I know" at the time of writing may be wrong, and is incomplete.  That being said, corrections are most welcome! Thank you!

My program is intended to be moved to a parent folder, and run to get files from child folders, so it ***may*** need to know its working directory. Unfortunately, there's no (that I've found) non-hacky method for getting this.

The following two lines of code will get you a path to the working directory of your Java app - NOTE: this *should be* the location the application is executed from.

Remember to import the appropriate libraries. I'm learning Java, so am not interested in learning anyone's favorite add-on library, so I stick only to Oracle Java libraries. LATER, when I have a decent handle on Java development, I'll start learning the cool, awesome capabilities of add-ons.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;
import static java.nio.file.FileVisitResult.*;
import static java.nio.file.FileVisitOption.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
```

NOTE: If you're getting "cannot find symbol" or compile-time errors on a method you grabbed from SO or another online resource, probably you don't have the right library imported. ...ask me how I know. ;)

There are several ways to go about getting the working directory, but because I need to pass the working directory to another function working with File, Path, FileSystems, etc, I wanted to use something "compatible". That isn't a thing, apparently.

```
    File workingDir = new File(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
    Path workDir = Paths.get(workingDir.getCanonicalPath());
```

The first line identifies the location where a 'new File' **can be** created, then grabs the absolute path of that potential file. The file name is "." - which could be a bit confusing...

The second line assigns the absolute path to the file "." (excluding the filename) to a variable. The Path starts at the root directory (i.e. drive letter in Windows environments). More info on absolute, canonical path can be found about 2/3 down here:
[Absolute/canonical path description](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/whats-the-difference-between-a-files-path-absolute-path-and-canonical-path.html)

Now my application knows where it is, I need an iterable object to pass entries into - this is the variable the files matching my regex will be passed into:

```
   java.util.List<String> files = new ArrayList<>();
```

Note: I have to include 'java.util.' in the 'List' declaration because I've imported other libraries that make the declaration ambiguous without it. None of that code is relevant, so is not included.

Now, onto the recursive search. Again, no non-hacky way to do this. I imagined this would be done commonly enough that a clean method would've been developed to do it - I mean, I know of at least 3 different ways to write a 'for' loop! - but I guess this reflects what the people at Oracle who develop Java use more than what mere 'users' (us) do with the product.

I chose to use a PathMatcher because I also need to specify folders to not search for files. 'Files.find()' and the numerous classes that talented people trying to be helpful programmed didn't have as straightforward a method for doing this.

```
final PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("regex:.*Correct_\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}_\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\.txt");
Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(workDir.toString()), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() 
{
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException
    {
        if (dir.getFileName().toString().equals("Reprocess"))
        {
             return SKIP_SUBTREE;
        }
        return CONTINUE;
    }//end public preVisitDirectory
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException 
    {
        if (matcher.matches(file))
        {
            files.add(file.toString());
        }//end if(matcher)
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }//end visitFile
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException 
    {
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }//end visitFileFailed
});//end Files.walkFileTree1
```

A couple notes on my code: 1. As a novice programmer, I find it helpful keeping track of my closing braces to label who each one belongs to; 2. My regex is highly specific, because I'm searching for a programmatic output - it gonna be the same every time.

**PathMatcher declaration:** Final instructs Java that this ain't changing. 'FileSystems.getDefault()' identifies the OS so the slashes point the right way (among other things). 'getPathMatcher(' executes a 'Pattern.compile()'-like function.

"regex:" defines the search as a 'regex', instead of 'glob' search. I broke this line out because it was difficult finding an example of the syntax for regex in this context.

Another note on my specific regex pattern: It doesn't work without the ".*", which denotes 'any number of preceding characters' - My hypothesis is that this accounts for the working directory being added as an absolute path to each file being searched for a match. ...took me a while to figure out why the working regex (I tested in a bufferedreader with some filenames pasted in) wasn't returning results.

**Files.walkFileTree:** Executing the 'walkFileTree' method of the Files class, with 'Paths.get(' as an argument. 'Paths.get(' has the working directory we established before as an argument.

Earlier, I mentioned using something "compatible" between Files, Path & FileSystems isn't a thing. Well, at my current skill-level, the only way I could pass a 'List' object in for the Path information, was to make it a string object first. So, we have "workDir.toString()". Hardcoding in the path to my working directory also worked, FYI.

NOTE: ".." specifies a relative path to the location the Java app was executed from. This is why I said earlier that my program "***may***" need to know its working directory - turns out mine doesn't, but yours might. I use my variable holding the absolute path to my working directory, instead (no observable effect on my code execution). You can pass in ".." (including double quotes) instead of 'workDir.toString()' if you just want a relative path location.

**new SimpleFileVisitor:** Instance of a simple file visitor.

The first argument specifies 'preVisitDirectory' instructions; this is where I instruct my program not to search inside the "Reprocess" folder. There are a lot of other instructions that can be inserted here, if needed.

The second argument specifies what my program should do when it finds a match - in this case the match is added to the 'files' ArrayList.

The third argument instructs the program not to sweat it when it doesn't find a match.

The end.

Well, not really, but this code does execute a recursive file search using regex, and outputs matches to a variable (ArrayList, in this case).

Getting the file names back out in a workable format is also turning out to be a chore. I'm certain this is because I defined the ArrayList as a String instead of a File (or other noob mistake, or three...).

Good luck! Feel free to contact me (if that's a thing) if you have any questions, comments or concerns.

Jake

**UPDATE:**
I was able to figure out how to pass filenames into a FileInputStream. Changes, below:

```
java.util.List<String> files = new ArrayList<>();
```

became:

```
java.util.List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
```

the visitFule argument in the 'Files.walkFileTree' function became:

```
public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException 
            {
                if (matcher.matches(file))
                {
                    files.add(file.toFile());
//'files.add(file.toString());' changed
                }//end if(matcher)
```

The following code was added to convert the 'files' ArrayList to fileArray, Array, then convert each element in the Array to a string at runtime, and pass that string to the FileInputStream (wrapped in a BufferedReader).

```
int fLength = files.size();
File[] fileArray = files.toArray(new File[fLength]);
for(int f=0; f<files.size(); f++)
{
//log file Reader init:
    String corrFile = fileArray[f].toString();
    BufferedReader corrReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(corrFile),"UTF-16LE"));
        //NOTE: PFO differential correction log files are encoded in UTF-16 LE
```

...aaand that's a wrap! This aspect of my project is complete, and working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The original issue you reported was `java:87: error: cannot find symbol" on 'Collector' in ".collect(Collectors.toList());`. Looking at the error the problem is well-stated - you did not import `java.util.stream.Collectors` in your code.

But once you imported it, you have another issue - `java:88: error: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds .collect(Collectors.toList());`. It usually means that the steam does not produce the type you need. You need a value for inputFiles, which is of type `List<String>`. The collection you get is `List<File>`, because you're using Path.toFile() in the map before. I suggest you remove the map (leave it as a list of paths) or change inputFiles to be a `List<File>`.

By the way, you can see how to go from to treat this error in this post, for example: [java: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719097/java-incompatible-types-inference-variable-t-has-incompatible-bounds-equality/41719150).

In general, it's best to debug your code one compilation error at a time, and simply look for posts in SO referring to the error you are getting. This kind of process may be iterative and take some time.